# file merge logic: scala

Tags: scala, hadoop

For scala experts this might be a silly question but me as a beginner facing hard time to identify the solution. Any pointers would help.

I've set of 3 files in HDFS location by the names:

```
fileFirst.dat
fileSecond.dat
fileThird.dat
```

Not necessarily they'll be stored in any order. `fileFirst.dat` could be created at very last so a `ls` every time would show different ordering of the files.

My task is to combine all files in a single file in the order:
fileFirst contents, then fileSecond contents & finally fileThird contents; with newline as the separator, no spaces.

I tried some ideas but couldn't come up with something working. Every time the order of combination messes up.

Below is my function to merge whatever is coming in:

```
  def writeFile(): Unit = {
    val in: InputStream = fs.open(files(i).getPath)
    try {
      IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, conf, false)
      if (addString != null) out.write(addString.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    } finally in.close()
}
```

`Files` is defined like this:

```
val files: Array[FileStatus] = fs.listStatus(srcPath)
```

This is part of a bigger function where I'm passing all the arguments used in this method. After everything is done, I'll do the `out.close()` to close the output stream.

Any ideas welcome, even if it goes against the file write logic I'm trying to do; just understand that I'm not that good in `scala`; for now :)

Comment: So... what exactly is your question? If it is just the ordering of files in `first, second, third...` order then your can rename them to `file1, file2, file3` etc... then sort the result of `fs.listStatus(srcPath)` using `filenames`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can enumerate your `Paths` directly, you don't really need to use `listStatus`. You could try something like this (untested):

```
val relativePaths = Array("fileFirst.dat", "fileSecond.dat", "fileThird.dat")
val paths = relativePaths.map(new Path(srcDirectory, _))
try {
    val output = fs.create(destinationFile)
    for (path <- paths) {
        try {
            val input = fs.open(path)
            IOUtils.copyBytes(input, output, conf, false)
        } catch {
            case ex => throw ex // Feel free to do some error handling here
        } finally {
            input.close()
        }
    }
} catch {
    case ex => throw ex // Feel free to do some error handling here
} finally {
    output.close()
}
```

Comment: I tested this logic francoisr, it just creates the 0 byte file; nothing writes in. Below is the tested code:

`try{
val output = fs.create(destinationFile)
for (path <- paths) {
val input = fs.open(path)
try{
IOUtils.copyBytes(input, output, conf, false)
if (newFile != null) output.write(newFile.getBytes("UTF-8"))
} finally input.close()
}
} catch { case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace 
}`

For now, have removed catches, was facing compilation issues.

Comment: This is strange. Have you checked that your input files are not empty?

Comment: Nope, inputs are perfect. No empty files.

Comment: This is strange. You might try to check whether you're able to copy a single file first.

Comment: Not sure what but I can merge the files if I directly call copyMerge utility. If I modify it as per my requirement, it doesn't even create the directory on local. My best guess is because I'm running the whole code via Spark, the executors that execute part of the code, they run via different user. So while copying the file, they would be facing permission issue.